# Comparing the value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Javascript/Jquery and I have a dropdownlist. My first index is: "Please select an id". I want to submit the page (return true will submit it) if something is selected, else do not submit it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Type() {
            var id = $("[id$='ddl1']").val();
            alert(id); // If something is selected i get the value else I get "Please select an id"
            var valid = false;
            if (id < 0) {
                $("#Type-span").text("*"); //A Span to represent the * if page not submitted            
            }
            else {
                valid = true;
                $("#Type-span").text(""); 
            }
            alert(valid);
        }
</script>
```

It always returns true here, even if i select "Please select an id"

Comment: Can  you show your html as well?

Comment: Well, `if('Please select an id' < 0)` will always be false.... so your condition is wrong.

Comment: You could have posted your HTML (or a fiddle preferred) by now rather than commenting on posts below as everyone of us is just assuming your  problem (HTML) which would yield no solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, try the below

```
var id = parseInt($("[id$='ddl1']").val(), 10);
```

To handle the NaN situation, you need to evaluate that too

```
if(id != id || id < 0)
```

and you should have value of element 'Please select an answer' as a blank.

Comment: `parseInt('Please select an id',10) === NaN == false`. So `parseInt($("[id$='ddl1']").val(), 10) || 0` will return `0` if no value is selected. `if (id < 0)` will always be false no matter what's selected.

Comment: Updated my answer. Sorry missed that zero is considered as a valid value.

Comment: Better, but still a small issue. If the value select is `0`, `parseInt($("[id$='ddl1']").val(), 10) || -1;` will be `-1`. You need to add an other check.

Comment: Yup, updated again. Handled the NaN situation and that zero is valid.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that the `value` attribute of is a string, so, if you are trying to compare it to `0`, I'm assuming that it is a number and you will need to convert it to one, before doing the compare.

Change this:

```
var id = $("[id$='ddl1']").val();
```

. . . to this:

```
var id = parseInt($("[id$='ddl1']").val(), 10);
```

And, if the `values` of the `<options>` are not all numbers (with the default being  `< 0`), then you need to make sure that they are.   :)

Comment: What does the parseInt("something", 10) means ? Does it mean to compare it with some numeric value ?

Comment: `parseInt` will read in a string value and return its integer equivalent. The `10` parameter determines what "base" to use for the conversion . . . so, "10" means, "interpret the string as a decimal value", whereas, "2" would treat it as a binary value, "16" a hexidecimal value, etc.  So, for example, `parseInt("11", 10);` would result in `11`, but `parseInt("11", 2);` would be `3` and `parseInt("11", 16);` would be `17`.